# Extra includes in visual studio's standard library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have noticed when you include one of the headers in the standard library in Visual Studio (such as `iostream`, `vector`, `set`, .. ) it also includes some other headers too.

```
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int A[1000];
    std::max(3,5);
    memset(A,0,sizeof(A));
    pow(2,2);
    printf("hi");
}
```

*above code compiles without any error in Visual Studio but in gcc it results in compilation error*

I assumed that Visual Studio includes some libraries by default. But after searching in the internet I found out that it's not true. So I realized this is because of the different implementation of the standard library in different compilers. So I want to know what is the reason behind this extra includes?
 I don't think `set` uses `pow` or `printf`.

Comment: This is one reason, for my own projects at least, I simply dump includes for the entire standard library in a precompiled header file, and force include it in my project settings. Now I never have to worry about updating my standard includes.

Comment: @NeilKirk: [That sounds like a really terrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085370/is-it-good-practice-to-use-bits-stdc-h-header-file). What problem, exactly, does it solve? The problem of bothering to read documentation?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The problem of having to check if I am including the header of every standard type I am using (compiling isn't enough, as it may be included indirectly), and having to check if I need to remove the header of every standard type I remove from the code, in case it is the last use. It's 2015, why do I need to do that manually? It also makes things compile faster.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I don't see how including the entire standard library "makes things compile faster" but okay

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm assuming a non-trivial C++ project uses large parts of the standard library anyway, and it goes in a **pre-compiled** header.

Comment: @NeilKirk: You know what assuming does.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Pretty well when talking about my **own** projects. Your mileage my vary.

Comment: @NeilKirk: At least qualify that when giving advice. :)

Comment: @NeilKirk: No, you said nothing about precompiled headers. I re-read it just to be sure!

Comment: I'm looking at it right now where it says that.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Er, so you did. Bollocks.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Can we pretend this never happened? :D

Comment: Lol ok, I pretend lots of things never happened ;)

Comment: @NeilKirk: That's what she said.

Comment: Yes, it causes a lot of conflict actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using -H parameter for gcc shows that including `set` results in including:

```
. include/c++/set
.. include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h
... include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h
.... include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/c++config.h
..... include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/os_defines.h
..... include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/cpu_defines.h
.... include/c++/bits/functexcept.h
..... include/c++/bits/exception_defines.h
.... include/c++/bits/cpp_type_traits.h
.... include/c++/ext/type_traits.h
.... include/c++/ext/numeric_traits.h
.... include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h
..... include/c++/bits/move.h
...... include/c++/bits/concept_check.h
.... include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h
.... include/c++/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h
..... include/c++/debug/debug.h
.... include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h
... include/c++/bits/allocator.h
.... include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/c++allocator.h
..... include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h
...... include/c++/new
....... include/c++/exception
........ include/c++/bits/atomic_lockfree_defines.h
.... include/c++/bits/memoryfwd.h
... include/c++/bits/stl_function.h
.... include/c++/backward/binders.h
.. include/c++/bits/stl_set.h
.. include/c++/bits/stl_multiset.h
.. include/c++/bits/range_access.h
```

And using /showIncludes for Visual Studio show that including `set` results in including:

```
VC\INCLUDE\set
 VC\INCLUDE\xtree
  VC\INCLUDE\xmemory
   VC\INCLUDE\xmemory0
    VC\INCLUDE\cstdlib
     VC\INCLUDE\yvals.h
      VC\INCLUDE\xkeycheck.h
      VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
       VC\INCLUDE\sal.h
        VC\INCLUDE\ConcurrencySal.h
       VC\INCLUDE\vadefs.h
      VC\INCLUDE\use_ansi.h
     VC\INCLUDE\stdlib.h
      VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
      VC\INCLUDE\limits.h
       VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
    VC\INCLUDE\limits
     VC\INCLUDE\ymath.h
     VC\INCLUDE\cfloat
      VC\INCLUDE\float.h
       VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
       VC\INCLUDE\crtwrn.h
        VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
     VC\INCLUDE\climits
     VC\INCLUDE\cmath
      VC\INCLUDE\math.h
       VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
      VC\INCLUDE\xtgmath.h
       VC\INCLUDE\xtr1common
     VC\INCLUDE\cwchar
      VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h
       VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
       VC\INCLUDE\swprintf.inl
       VC\INCLUDE\wtime.inl
     VC\INCLUDE\xstddef
      VC\INCLUDE\cstddef
       VC\INCLUDE\stddef.h
        VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
    VC\INCLUDE\new
     VC\INCLUDE\exception
      VC\INCLUDE\eh.h
       VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
      VC\INCLUDE\malloc.h
       VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
      VC\INCLUDE\string.h
       VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
    VC\INCLUDE\xutility
     VC\INCLUDE\utility
      VC\INCLUDE\iosfwd
       VC\INCLUDE\cstdio
        VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h
         VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
       VC\INCLUDE\cstring
       VC\INCLUDE\crtdbg.h
        VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
      VC\INCLUDE\type_traits
       VC\INCLUDE\xrefwrap
    VC\INCLUDE\xatomic0.h
    VC\INCLUDE\intrin.h
     VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
     VC\INCLUDE\setjmp.h
      VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
     VC\INCLUDE\immintrin.h
      VC\INCLUDE\wmmintrin.h
       VC\INCLUDE\nmmintrin.h
        VC\INCLUDE\smmintrin.h
         VC\INCLUDE\tmmintrin.h
          VC\INCLUDE\pmmintrin.h
           VC\INCLUDE\emmintrin.h
            VC\INCLUDE\xmmintrin.h
             VC\INCLUDE\mmintrin.h
              VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
     VC\INCLUDE\ammintrin.h
     VC\INCLUDE\mm3dnow.h
      VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
      VC\INCLUDE\mmintrin.h
  VC\INCLUDE\stdexcept
   VC\INCLUDE\xstring
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to occur.

`<set>` will pull in anything that `<set>` uses in its declarations. For example, it will pull in `<memory>` for [`std::allocator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits).

In turn, everything that `<set>` pulls in will pull other stuff in. Etc... If one of those headers includes `<cmath>` you've suddenly got `std::pow`.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when those headers need the other headers to work.

It is completely implementation-dependent. Just as you need to include headers in your own code, the people who create these headers need to include other headers in *their* code to make it work.

Don't rely on it. Always include what *you* need.